# Stuck with Unprocessed document in Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am using unprocessed document so that it will run on selected document only  , but after selection its looking for column values in a view to export document to excel . I am using the below code its working fine but my first document is always displaying in last after all other exported documents in excel sheet . Any idea what can be done with the code so that Exported document display perfectly in order as in the view.

Look at the below code which I used for exporting –

```
Sub Initialize

 'On Error Goto errhandler
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim doccoll As NotesDocumentCollection
 Dim view As NotesView 
 Dim doc As NotesDocument
 Dim otherdoc As NotesDocument

 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase 
 Set view = db.GetView("CRMOpenIssue") 
 Set doccoll=db.UnprocessedDocuments

 Set oExcel = CreateObject ( "Excel.Application" )
 Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
 Set oWorkSheet= oWorkbook.Sheets ( 1 )


 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,1).value="Quote# "
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,2).value="Quote Line#" 
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,3).value="Customer - fab"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,4).value="OppNum"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,5).value="OppLine#" 
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,6).value="Open Issue#"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,7).value="Open Issue"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,8).value="Category"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,9).value="Due date"
 oWorkSheet.Cells(1,10).value="Owner to resolve issue"
 'oWorkSheet.Cells(1,11).value="Owner/PME Verify when closed"
 oExcel.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J1").Font.Bold = True

 oExcel.columns("A:A").ColumnWidth=15.00
 oExcel.columns("B:B").ColumnWidth=8.00
 oExcel.columns("C:C").ColumnWidth=15.00
 oExcel.columns("D:D").ColumnWidth=10.00
 oExcel.columns("E:E").ColumnWidth=8.00
 oExcel.columns("F:F").ColumnWidth=8.00 
 oExcel.columns("G:G").ColumnWidth=30.00
 oExcel.columns("H:H").ColumnWidth=30.00
 oExcel.columns("I:I").ColumnWidth=15.00
 oExcel.columns("J:J").ColumnWidth=15.00
 'oExcel.columns("K:K").ColumnWidth=30.00

 row% = 1
 offset% = 0
 lastOffset% = 0 

 If doccoll.count >1 Then 'if more than one doc selected then confirm 
  resp = Messagebox("Do you want to export only the " & _
  "selected " & doccoll.count & " documents?", 36, "Selected only?" )
 Else
  Messagebox "Exporting all rows. (To export only selected " & _
  "rows tick those required in the left margin first.)"
 End If  '6= yes 

 oExcel.visible=True
 Dim i As Integer
 If resp=6 Then 'selected documents
  Set doc = doccoll.GetFirstDocument   
  While Not doc Is Nothing
   If resp=6 Then  

    'row% = offset% + 2
    If y="" Then
     row% = row% + 2
    Else 
     row%=row%+y+1
    End If
    col% = 0 'Reset the Columns
    Set otherdoc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
    If otherdoc Is Nothing Then
     Set otherdoc = view.getprevdocument(doc)
     If otherdoc Is Nothing Then
      Print " >1 doc should be selected"
      End
     Else
      Set otherdoc = view.getnextdocument(otherdoc)
     End If
    Else 'got next doc
     Set otherdoc = view.getprevdocument(otherdoc)
    End If        
   End If
   Forall colval In otherdoc.ColumnValues
    col% = col% + 1

    If Isarray(colval) Then
     ''If col%=10 Then   ''''''''
     columnVal=Fulltrim(colval)
     For y = 0 To Ubound(columnVal)
      offset% = row% + y +lastOffset%   
      'offset% = row% + y  
      oWorkSheet.Cells(offset%,col%).value = columnVal(y) 
      'i=offset%
     Next
    Else
     oWorkSheet.Cells(row%, col%).value = colval 
     'offset% = offset% + 1
    End If
    '''' oWorkSheet.Cells(row%, col%).value = colval '''''
    '''''''End If''''''''
   End Forall

   Set doc = doccoll.GetNextDocument(doc)       
  Wend
 End if
```

Comment: Your loops are borked, and you have strange logic - e.g. why check the collection size *in* the loop? Why check the value of `resp` *in the loop*? If you clean up how you iterate your documents, everything else will follow.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the points of Ben, Alexey and Ken, I think that part of the problem was left untouched - how do you get to export `ColumnValues`, when the `NotesDocumentCollection` you have:

1. Contains `NotesDocument` objects, which `ColumnValues` property is not set. `ColumnValues` is only set for documents you get through a `NotesView` object. This is what Rupesh tries to solve with the doc/otherdoc messy part.
2. Is not guaranteed to be sorted the way it is displayed through the view.

The above is true whether you get the selected documents using `NotesDatabase.UnprocessedDocuments` or `NotesUIView.Documents`, both of which return the selected documents when used in a view action.
I've had similar problem in the past and while I don't have the code I'll try to describe a workable solution:

1. Get the selected documents using either `NotesDatabase.UnprocessedDocuments` or `NotesUIView.Documents`
2. Build a list with the `UniversalId`s of the selected documents
3. Get the `ViewEntryCollection` of all entries in the view
4. Loop through all entries in the `ViewEntryCollection`
5. For each `ViewEntry` check if `ViewEntry.IsDocument`
6. If True, check if `ViewEntry.UniversalId` is part of the previously built list
7. If True, export the `ViewEntry.ColumnValues`

Here is a working test with an alternative approach for checking whether the current `ViewEntry` in the loop is actually one of the selected documents:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim selectedDc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim tempDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim allVec As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim tempVe As NotesViewEntry
    Dim thisView As NotesView
    Dim thisDb As NotesDatabase
    Dim session As New NotesSession

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim thisUiView As NotesUIView

    Set thisUiView = ws.CurrentView
    Set selectedDc = thisUiView.Documents

    If (selectedDc.Count = 0) Then
        Messagebox "No selected documents!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set thisDb = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set thisView = thisUiView.View
    Set allVec = thisView.AllEntries

    Set tempVe = allVec.GetFirstEntry
    While Not tempVe Is Nothing

        If (tempVe.IsDocument) Then
            Set tempDoc = selectedDc.GetDocument(thisDb.GetDocumentByUNID(tempVe.UniversalID))
            If Not (tempDoc Is Nothing) Then
                Messagebox Cstr(tempVe.ColumnValues(1))
            End If
        End If

        Set tempVe = allVec.GetNextEntry(tempVe)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Note: This is a fairly old question, but I post this answer because of the tricky part of going from the selected documents to exporting them in the order they appear in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove this whole section:

```
Set otherdoc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
If otherdoc Is Nothing Then
 Set otherdoc = view.getprevdocument(doc)
 If otherdoc Is Nothing Then
  Print " >1 doc should be selected"
  End
 Else
  Set otherdoc = view.getnextdocument(otherdoc)
 End If
Else 'got next doc
 Set otherdoc = view.getprevdocument(otherdoc)
End If
```

End If

I'm not sure what you were going for, but it appears you were testing that more than one document is selected.  You can do that easily by testing the doccoll.count property:

```
If doccoll.count <=1 Then  'etc...
```

Then just change your Forall statement to work on doc instead of otherdoc:

```
Forall colval In doc.ColumnValues ...
```

Comment: Hi Ken , Columnvalues do not work for unprocessed document .I tried it and found that it was not fetching column value ,if would then it would be really easy for me to export document to excel.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand completely what this loop is for. UnprocessedDocuments is just a NotesDocumentsCollection. You navigate through it using GetFirstDocument/GetNextDocument in a while loop or similar. Warning indicating that no documents were selected should come in first place, not in the loop.

```
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doccoll = db.UnprocessedDocuments
If doccoll.Count = 0 Then
  Print " >1 doc should be selected"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

after that you do your Excel initialization and loop

```
Set doc = doccoll.GetFirstDocument
While Not doc Is Nothing
  ' enter code here'

  Set doc = doccoll.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

Regarding columns I would double check. NotesDocument is just an object that should behave the same way always. But Notes is Notes... I will check also and give you a feedback.